# Cannot hide div

Tags: html, css, hidden

I've added a (almost) minimal example to https://jsfiddle.net/p5uo12td/
I'd like the "Message Subimitted!" message to be hidden when the webpage is loaded, so that the message could get visible after good submission.

But can't find the way to make it not visible.

```
// html
<div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden">Message Submitted!</div>

// css
#msgSubmit .hidden {
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #0a0a0e;
}
```

Comment: There should not be a space between `#msgSubmit` and  `.hidden`.

Comment: #msgSubmit, .hidden

Comment: @Talgat No. It would be #msgSubmit.hidden

Comment: Such a beginner mistake in my front-end intake...  Thanks both of you.

Comment: @Turnip, sorry, but it worked in jsFiddle. It hides the div.

Comment: @Talgat the comma makes it two separate selectors. It would mean: hide `#msgSubmit` and also hide _any_ other element with the class `hidden`.

Comment: @Turnip, thanks, I thought that is the thing Luis was searching for. He intended to hide both.

Comment: @Luis, please correct me if I am wrong.